# how to keep the same amount of a background image visible as screen sizes change?

Tags: css, image, background, screen

Is it possible using only CSS to replicate how as screen sizes change but the same amount of image is seen? I have been able to scale the image but the amount of the image seen changes as screen sizes change. I am fairly new to learning CSS and appreciate any help.

I am trying to replicate this site. Just the initial section and first image.

https://ayesha.dropletthemes.com/home-beauty-salon/

Comment: There is no way the same amount of an image can be seen on all possible viewports if you use say cover as the viewports will have different aspect ratios. You can force the whole image to always be visible by using contain. Or go further and clip it consistently, but in both those cases there will be blank space either at the sides or top and bottom. What do you want to happen?

Comment: you could make it stretch/squish to always show the same amount but that wouldn't look very good - what are you trying to achieve?